# How can I share a Module's androidTest "Robots" with another module?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I am a big fan of the [Robot](https://academy.realm.io/posts/kau-jake-wharton-testing-robots/) pattern for keeping UI tests clean. But how can I reuse Robot classes across multiple modules?

```
:lib-with-ui . // has Robot classes in `src/androidTest`
:app
```

I fully test my `lib-with-ui` with the Robot classes, however I want to reuse those same Robot classes in the `:app` module for some quick smoke testing.

For why the smoke testing is useful, it's because we want to test the integration of all our components as well as catch any possible proguarding issue that may occur (we have a special flavor of our sample app that utilizes proguarded AARs of our libraries).

We've tried a variety of approaches to get this to work, but it has all lead to weird resource issues.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but maybe it will help future readers.

We'll soon be able to fully utilise the `testFixtures` capability in Android also which allows for exactly this. - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139438142.

Until then / otherwise:

- robots could stay in a separate library, say `robots`:

  - which depends on your `:lib-with-ui` - (`implementation(:lib-with-ui)`)
- `:lib-with-ui` tests can depend on your new `:robots` libray.
  (by using `androidTestImplementation(:robots)` in `:lib-with-ui`) and avoid the cyclic dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Robot classes are defined in module 'lib-with-ui' and you want to use this in module 'app'?

Add lib-with-ui android library module as dependency to app module. Any code and resources in the Android library is now accessible to your app module, and the library AAR file is bundled into your APK at build time.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency

Comment: the robot classes are defined in `androidTestImplementation`, not the main source set